# Should I use duplicate units to raise SA or unlock potential routes?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

When I get a duplicate of a UR unit, is it more beneficial to use the duplicate unit in training to raise the SA of my main unit or should I use the duplicate unit to unlock hidden potential routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Unlock potential routes.

Long(er) anwser: There are multiple ways to raise the SA level of a unit, but there is only one way to unlock a route. Therefore it is recommended that you unlock a potential route over raising the SA level of a unit.